# Pop Implementation for a stack without a memory leak

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I am attempting to create my own stack of ints (struct int_stack) that is a linked list of a struct I created (struct is_node). I want to do this with no occurrences of memory leaks, but I can't figure out how to implement the pop method. The pop method takes in paramaters (int_stack) and returns an int. Lets say node_capacity is set to 5, there are 6 ints in the stack (meaning 2 nodes) one that is full, and one that has only one int, and pop is called. It should return the value of the int on the node with only 1, but it needs to free the array of ints on a node and also free the node. I'm not sure how to free an int, and then return it, without causing a memory leak. This is what I am trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "int_stack.h"

struct int_stack *make_stack(int node_capacity) {
  //malloc theseprintf("%d]", temp->contents[i]);
  struct is_node *head;
  struct int_stack *stacky;
  head = malloc(sizeof(struct is_node));
  stacky = malloc(sizeof(struct int_stack));
  stacky->node_capacity = node_capacity;
  head->contents = malloc(node_capacity * sizeof(int));
  head->next_index = 0;
  head->next = NULL;
  stacky->size = 0;
  stacky->head = head;
  return stacky;
}

void free_stack(struct int_stack *stk) {
  struct is_node *pointee;
  pointee = stk->head;
  while (stk->head->next != NULL) {
    pointee = stk->head->next;
    free(stk->head->contents);
    free(stk->head);
    stk->head = pointee;
  }
  free(stk->head->contents);
  free(stk->head);
  free(stk);
}

void reset_stack(struct int_stack *stk) {
  struct is_node *temp;
  while (stk->head->next != NULL) {
    temp = stk->head->next;
    free(stk->head->contents);
    free(stk->head);
    stk->head = temp;
  }
  stk->size = 0;
  stk->head->contents = NULL;
  stk->head->next_index = 0;
}

void print_stack(struct int_stack *stk) {
  struct is_node *temp;
  int i;
  temp = stk->head;
  i = temp->next_index - 1;
  if (is_empty(stk) == 1) {
    printf("(]");
  }
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (i == temp->next_index - 1) {
      if (i == stk->node_capacity - 1) {
        if (i == 0) {
          printf("[%d]",temp->contents[i]);
        } else {
          printf("[%d,",temp->contents[i]);
      }
      } else if (i == 0) {
        printf("(%d]",temp->contents[i]);
      } else {
        printf("(%d,",temp->contents[i]);
      }
    } else {
      if (i == 0) {
        printf("%d]", temp->contents[i]);
      } else {
        printf("%d,",temp->contents[i]);
      }
    }
    if (i == 0 && temp->next != NULL) {
      temp = temp->next;
      i = temp->next_index;
    }
    --i;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int is_empty(struct int_stack *stk) {
  if (stk->size == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

void push(struct int_stack *stk, int v) {
  stk->size++;
  int i = stk->head->next_index;
  if ((stk->size % stk->node_capacity == 1 && stk->size > stk->node_capacity) || (stk->node_capacity == 1)) {
    struct is_node *new_head;
    new_head = malloc(sizeof(struct is_node));
    new_head->contents = malloc(sizeof(stk->node_capacity * sizeof(int)));
    new_head->next = stk->head;
    new_head->next_index = 1;
    new_head->contents[0] = v;
    stk->head = new_head;
  } else {
    stk->head->contents[i] = v;
    stk->head->next_index = realloc();
  }
}

int pop(struct int_stack *stk) {
  int pop_val;
  struct is_node *temp;
  if (is_empty(stk) == 1) {
    return -1;
  } else if (stk->head->next_index == 1) {
    pop_val = stk->head->contents[0];
    stk->size = stk->size - 1;
    stk->head->next_index = 0;
    if (stk->head->next != NULL) {
      temp = stk->head->next;
      free(stk->head->contents);
      free(stk->head);
      stk->head = temp;
    }
    return pop_val;
  } else {
    pop_val = stk->head->contents[stk->head->next_index - 1];
    stk->head->next_index = stk->head->next_index - 1;
    stk->size = stk->size - 1;
    return pop_val;
  }
}

int top(struct int_stack *stk) {
  if (is_empty(stk) != 1) {
    return stk->head->contents[stk->head->next_index - 1];
  }
  return -1;
}
```

And my structs are defined as:

```
 struct is_node {
   int *contents;
   int next_index;
   struct is_node *next;
 };

 struct int_stack {
   int size;
   int node_capacity;
   struct is_node *head;
 };
```

Comment: If it is a linked list, then `size` and `node_capacity` are completely unnecessary; you just walk the list and if there is no `next`, you are at the end. Your code seems overly complex for such a simple task. Suggest you go back to the drawing board.

Comment: If you're only storing `ints`, why are you allocating memory for them? Just put the `int` in the node.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie My guess is they are storing blocks of ints on each node to increase the chance of a cache hit. Not that a heap-allocated stack is how I'd consider doing that in the first place if that was the concern, but there are "potential use cases" for that structure.

Comment: It's for an assignment, and yes, it is a stack that is made up of nodes that hold an array of ints, and the user can choose how large that array is by setting the node capacity. I will update this to include my method to make the stack.

Comment: Updated with push

Comment: In `make_stack`, `stacky->size` should be set to 1 as there is one node. Size is again completely unnecesary as you can walk the list.

Comment: No, size is referring to the ints that it currently holds. Size shouldn't be 1 until the first time push is called.

Comment: @CharlotteK.: You want to delete the element from `contents` array which is popped?

Comment: @coderredoc Technically yes, but I initially allocate an array of 5 ints when creating a node, so when I am deleting a node, I delete the space for those 5 ints. I never free the space for one int, it is always an entire array of size node_capacity.

Comment: It works, but it is leaking memory somewhere. I'm not sure where, but the gcc compiler is giving me a warning in the pop method: 
    int_stack.c:113:13: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion
      assigning to 'int *' from 'int'; take the address with &
    pop_val = stk->head->contents[0]; so I figure the leak is in the pop method and I am wondering if I am simply using my pointers incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your return value pop_val is not leaked in this case. As a local variable it's allocated on the stack, not the heap and does not need to be freed.

Answer (score 0):

THe thing is you want to dynamically allocate deallocate the nodes of the stack.

Now let's consider the design which has two parts:-

1. You are creating an head node which will basically store all the meta information regarding the list and as well the beginning of the list.
2. Now before you were using an dynamically created array for that. Now let's look into the  thing more closely. To delete a node of stack (stack-node) you will have to delete the whole allocated `contents` and create new one with all the other elements. This is one way but it is very very inefficient in that allocating deallocating for every pop etc.

What about changing the design a bit?

Keep the head node as you have kept. And then keep a `stack-node*`. Now everytime you push, create a new stack node and then add it to the `head`. Similarly when you pop just delete that node from `head`. No need to keep an array. Just put the data in separate nodes and that's it. This will make your code a lot simple.